# An a start tag seen but an element of the same type was already open

Tags: html

Hey im getting three errors while trying to validate my project, they are 'An a start tag seen but an element of the same type was already open.' , 'End tag a violates nesting rules.' and 'Cannot recover after last error. Any further errors will be ignored.' 
The errors while validating point to the '>' in ''.
Im new on html and cant figure out why this is happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

```
<body> 

<a href="index.html"><img class = "banner" src="banner.jpg" alt="Image"/>


<nav>
 <a href="index.html">Home</a> | 
 <a href="product2.html">Products</a> | 
 <a href="about.html">About</a> 
</nav>
```

Comment: most of the tags needs to be closed and some are not like `<img>`. In your case anchor tag or `<a>` is partnered with `</a>`

Answer (score 1):

You're missing your closing anchor tag:

```
<a href="index.html"><img class = "banner" src="banner.jpg" alt="Image"/> <--HERE
```

Change it to:

```
<a href="index.html"><img class = "banner" src="banner.jpg" alt="Image"/></a>
```

Comment: Oops how'd i miss that?! Thank you!